# Undefined references to SDL when building with mingw

Tags: mingw, sdl, gnu-make

I'm trying to build https://github.com/LTCHIPS/rottexpr

I've dropped the contents of SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw.tar.gz and SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4 into my mingw folder, so for example `mingw\include\SDL2\SDL.h` exists. when I run `cd src; make all`, it gets through most of the build fine but when it gets to `ld` I get a bunch of errors such as `mingw32/bin/ld.exe:`[...]`src\audiolib/dsl.c:190: undefined reference to 'Mix_PlayChannelTimed'`. There's a bunch of those, all with SDL-sounding names (`SDL_InitSubSystem`), except for one at the very end, which is a reference to `WinMain@16`. Googling for the WinMain16 error took me to a page which suggested that the problem was that I was trying to cross-link between 32-bit and 64-bit, but (as far as I can tell), I'm not. The places in the zip I extracted from were `SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw.tar-1\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\` and `SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-mingw.tar\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"suggested that the problem was that I was trying to cross-link between 32-bit and 64-bit"* That would be my guess too. You seem be using x64 libraries, what happens if you try x32 ones?

Comment: not sure how to do that-- for both sdl2 and sdl2_mixer, the available developer downloads are for mingw32 or for Visual C++ (the runtimes are split by 32 vs 64 but I'm not at runtime yet). Inside those downloads there's an i686 folder and an x86_64 folder. i686 is for ARM right? I don't have an ARM processor, so I copied from the x86_64 folder

Comment: You want i686. Essentially, i686 is x32 and x86_64 is x64.

Comment: alright, I reinstalled sdl2 and sdl2_mixer from the i686 folder but `make -B all` still produces the same errors`

Comment: Are you *sure* that you don't have stray x64 libraries somewhere?

Comment: I'm not, but I don't know how to check or correct that